# Pass data from one reactive part to other in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

In the shiny app below I would like to use the dataframe `dt`, from the `reactive` called data, in the `renderPlot`.

I tried this in different ways by: `ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()` and by `ggplot(data(), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()`

I just cannot figure out how to transfer the dataframe from one reactive part to another.

**EDIT**
I think I found the solution by using: `ggplot(data()$dt, aes(x,y) + ...` But now the problem seems to be in the `filter` from the `dplyr` packages.

Any tips?

server:

```
# server

library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)) %>%
  mutate(id = ntile(x, 4))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  data <- reactive({

    dt <- dt %>%
      filter(id == input$id)

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(dt, aes(x,y) +
      geom_point()

  })


})
```

ui:

```
## ui

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(width = 2,

               selectInput("id", 
                           "Select ID:",
                           c(1:4))

               ),
  mainPanel(width = 10,

            plotOutput("plot")

            )

))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code (what you provide doesn't even run), but most importantly you have to understand how reactives work. I suggest reading through the shiny tutorial again, especially the sections about reactive variables.  When rendering the plot, you want to use the value of `data`, not of `dt`.

Other errors:

- you defined a dataframe `df` but in your subsequent code you're using a non existent variable `dt`
- You don't have a closing parenthesis on the ggplot call

Here's a working version of your code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)) %>%
  mutate(id = ntile(x, 4))

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,

                 selectInput("id", 
                             "Select ID:",
                             c(1:4))

    ),
    mainPanel(width = 10,

              plotOutput("plot")

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    data <- reactive({

      df <- df %>%
        filter(id == input$id)
      df
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({

      ggplot(data(), aes(x,y)) +
               geom_point()

    })

  }
))
```